# How can I optimize the spark function to replace nulls with zeroes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my Spark Function which handles nulls in a DataFrame column irrespective of its datatype.

```
  def nullsToZero(df:DataFrame,nullsToZeroColsList:Array[String]): DataFrame ={
    var y:DataFrame = df
    for(colDF <- y.columns){
      if(nullsToZeroColsList.contains(colDF)){
        y = y.withColumn(colDF,expr("case when "+colDF+" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "+colDF+" end"))
      }
    }
    return y
  }

    import spark.implicits._
    val personDF = Seq(
      ("miguel", Some(12),100,110,120), (null, Some(22),200,210,220), ("blu", None,300,310,320)
    ).toDF("name", "age","number1","number2","number3")
    println("Print Schema")
    personDF.printSchema()
    println("Show Original DF")
    personDF.show(false)
    val myColsList:Array[String] = Array("name","age","age")
    println("NULLS TO ZERO")
    println("Show NullsToZeroDF")
    val fixedDF = nullsToZero(personDF,myColsList)
```

In the above code I've a Integer type and a String type datatypes, both were handled by my funciton.
But I suspect the below piece of code, in my function might affect the performance but not sure.

```
y = y.withColumn(colDF,expr("case when "+colDF+" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "+colDF+" end"))
```

Is there any more optimized way I can write this function, and what is the significance of doing .withColumn() and reassigning a DF again and again?
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest assembling a `valueMap` for [`na.fill(valueMap)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@fill(valueMap:Map[String,Any]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) to fill `null` columns with specific values in accordance with the data types, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (Some(1), Some("a"), Some("x"), None),
  (None,    Some("b"), Some("y"), Some(20.0)),
  (Some(3), None,      Some("z"), Some(30.0))
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val nullColList = List("c1", "c2", "c4")

val valueMap = df.dtypes.filter(x => nullColList.contains(x._1)).
  collect{ case (c, t) => t match {
    case "StringType" => (c, "n/a")
    case "IntegerType" => (c, 0)
    case "DoubleType" => (c, Double.MinValue)
  } }.toMap
// valueMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = 
//   Map(c1 -> 0, c2 -> n/a, c4 -> -1.7976931348623157E308)

df.na.fill(valueMap).show
// +---+---+---+--------------------+
// | c1| c2| c3|                  c4|
// +---+---+---+--------------------+
// |  1|  a|  x|-1.79769313486231...|
// |  0|  b|  y|                20.0|
// |  3|n/a|  z|                30.0|
// +---+---+---+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is Really nice Leo, it is a perfect shot for a DF in which all columns have to be handled, but in my case, I don't have to handle all the columns for a given DF, only a list of columns I've to worry about. 
I can still use the above method, Create
val x =  DF diff listOfColumns, and then perform the above on listOfColumns and add the DF back to the original DF.
The way I am doing in the Question, will it impact performance?

Comment: @Pavan_Obj, please see revised solution that handles selected columns.  I would expect a single transformation via `na.fill` works more efficiently than multiple transformations via `withColumn`.

Comment: Beautifully written, I've tested my code which ran for 40 - 50 minutes, I am going to run with this change and leave the --conf spark as is.

Comment: Thanks, Leo, this also helped me to do something like below
```val myNewMap:Map[String,Any] = Map("someStringTypeCol" -> null, "someIntTypeCol" -> null, "someStringTypeCol" -> 0)```
Just incase if I've to .fill the like above.